# Adjusting Figures (Floats) Next to Tables

Tags: floats, positioning

I am wondering what is the best way to place floats directly across from a array or tabular environment. I want to get the graph to show on the right of the table of values. A picture is shown below along with a `MWE`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{array}{rr}
  -7.0 & 7.0 \\
  -6.0 & 0.067 \\
  -5.0 & -4.9 \\
  -4.0 & -7.7 \\
  -3.0 & -7.9 \\
  -2.0 & -2.9 \\
  -1.0 & 39. \\
   0 & 87. \\
   1.0 & 50. \\
   2.0 & 21. \\
   3.0 & 28. \\
   4.0 & 40. \\
   5.0 & 55. \\
   6.0 & 72. \\
   7.0 & 91.
\end{array}
$

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\scalebox{0.5}{
\includegraphics{hx.pdf}
              }
\caption{Plot of the function \( h(x) \)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the caption to encompass only the graph, then something like this could be what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{\fill}$
\begin{array}{rr}
  -7.0 & 7.0 \\
  -6.0 & 0.067 \\
  -5.0 & -4.9 \\
  -4.0 & -7.7 \\
  -3.0 & -7.9 \\
  -2.0 & -2.9 \\
  -1.0 & 39. \\
   0 & 87. \\
   1.0 & 50. \\
   2.0 & 21. \\
   3.0 & 28. \\
   4.0 & 40. \\
   5.0 & 55. \\
   6.0 & 72. \\
   7.0 & 91.
\end{array}
$\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{hx.pdf}
\caption{Plot of the function \( h(x) \)}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `graphicx` and its extended syntax, that avoids the `\scalebox` command (the `demo` option is just to produce the example without needing a file). Adjust to suit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Include your array inside the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
$
\begin{array}{rr}
  -7.0 & 7.0 \\
  -6.0 & 0.067 \\
  -5.0 & -4.9 \\
 ..............
   7.0 & 91.
\end{array}
$
\qquad
\scalebox{0.5}{
\includegraphics{hx.pdf}
              }
\caption{Plot of the function \( h(x) \)}
\end{figure}
```

While you're at it, maybe you want to change that `array` into a `tabular`, and add a couple `\hline`s,  and/or use the package `booktabs`.

Comment: This does it, but one thing. I am not looking for the figure caption to be underneath the table of values, just only right under the figure.

Comment: Then you probably want to have a look at the `wrapfig` package, and use the `wrapfigure` environment.